# How to push an object in a object - javascript

Tags: javascript, object, addition

I have two ways to fill the same hidden input in a form

1. Using an import CSV button
2. Adding data using another inputs

When I use the first option, the hidden input is filled with this

for example:

**correct data**

```
[{"url":"http://www.restaurant.com","businessTypeId":"1"},{"url":"http://www.hotel.com","businessTypeId":"2"}]
```

and works correctly if I store this data

but when I use the second option, the input is filled with this:

**incorrect data**

```
{"url":"http://www.google.com","businessTypeId":"3"}
```

That's incorrect because it doesn't have **[brackets]** at the beginning neither at the end

**Another problem is when I insert data and fill that hidden input (with the first way) and then I try to add more data using the second way,
I get this**

```
[{"url":"http://www.restaurant.com","businessTypeId":"1"}, 
{"url":"http://www.hotel.com","businessTypeId":"2"}], 
{"url":"http://www.google.com","businessTypeId":"3"}
```

the first 2 data was inserted using the first way, the third data was inserted using the 2nd way

all data should be inside those brackets []

how can I "open" the brackets to push new data and "close" them?

at the beginning of all the code, **the variable starts like this**

```
let placesArray = [];
```

**after the first method, data is inserted using this**

```
placesArray.push(JSON.stringify(csvResult));
document.getElementById('places').value = placesArray;
```

**them, after the second method, data is inserted using this**

```
 placesArray.push(JSON.stringify(placeData));
 console.log('placeData datatable ' + placeData);
 document.getElementById('places').value = placesArray;
```

**Note: if I use the first method two times, brackets are duplicated, like this**

```
[{"url":"http://www.restaurant.com","businessTypeId":"1"}
{"url":"http://www.hotel.com","businessTypeId":"2"}],
[{"url":"http://www.beauty-shop.com","businessTypeId":"3"},
{"url":"http://www.dentist.com","businessTypeId":"5"}]
```

I definitely need to "open" the object so that I can insert the new data and not go through this, how could I do that?

In the console.log, I have this for `placeData` `[object Object]`, same result for `csvResult`, both are object

Answer (score 1):

You could [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the array before every value set

```
placesArray = placesArray.flat()
document.getElementById('places').value = placesArray;
```

Comment: the result is the same :(

Comment: your answer helped me with other problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `csvResult` is itself an array and as you stringify it and push it to `placesArray`, it doesn't look like the result you want.

I'd go with this instead

```js
placesArray.push(...csvResult) // push each `csvResult` item into `placesArray`
document.getElementById('places').value = JSON.stringify(placesArray)
```

Comment: csvResult is an object, because when I see the console, the log is [object Object]

Comment: placeData is an object too, in the log of the console I have this [object Object] for placeData too

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

I erased all JSON.stringify and added it to every line when I push data into inputs

like this

```
document.getElementById('places').value = JSON.stringify(placesArray);
```

in all lines when this is used.

thanks to @hgb123

for prevent to accumulate [brackets[more brackets]] I used .flat()

```
placesArray = placesArray.flat()
document.getElementById('places').value = JSON.stringify(placesArray);
```